# is it possible to do Math on Variable Values in Regex?

Tags: regex, search

i am wondering of it is possible to do some simple Math on RegEx Variable values.
E.G.:

I am looking for all two-digit numbers is a textfile and would like to multiply them by 10.
Is simple regex able to do this or do i need to use a more complex script for that?

thanks!

Comment: Really a bad idea to do math on regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply two-digits number is like appending `0` at the end of the numbers. So that can be done with any regular expression that support replace and capturing group.

For example, here is Python code:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\b(\d{2})\b', r'\g<1>0', 'There are 10 apples.')
'There are 100 apples.'
```

But what you want is multiply by arbitrary number, then you need the regular expression engine that support some kind of callback / evaluation.

```
>>> re.sub(r'\b(\d{2})\b', lambda m: str(int(m.group(1)) * 5), '10 apples.')
'50 apples.'
```

Comment: thanks, of course the latter is what i wanted, multiply by 10 was just an example ;)